# A problem involving centralizer and cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I have just begun studying the group $S_n$ and I am having trouble with the cycle notation so this problem seems a bit hard. Any help will be deeply appreciated:

> If $a \in S_n$ is an $n$-cycle or an $(n-1)$-cycle then the centralizer of $a$ is equal to the cyclic group $\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: Hint: if you conjugate a cycle $a$ by another cycle $b$, all you have to do is apply the $b$ permutation to the numbers in cycle $a$.  For example, $(1234)^{(12)}=(2134)$.  (You should prove this if you plan to use it!)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be an $m$-cycle. The number of conjugates of $a$ is the number of $m$-cycles, which is:
$$
\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m}
$$

By the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem), the number of conjugates of $a$ is:
$$
\frac{\left|S_n\right|}{\left|C_{S_n}(a)\right|} = \frac{n!}{\left|C_{S_n}(a)\right|}
$$

Where $C_{S_n}(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$ in $S_n$. It follows that:
$$
\left|C_{S_n}(a)\right| = m (n-m)! \tag{1}
$$

Since $a$ commutes with all elements in the cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$, we have:
$$
\langle a \rangle \le C_{S_n}(a) \tag{2}
$$

For $m \in \{n-1, n\}$, $(1)$ gives $\left|C_{S_n}(a)\right| = m$. Since $\left|\langle a \rangle\right| = m$, we have equality in $(2)$.